# mongoDB, c++ libmongoclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver

when I build my cpp project in cpp...this is the oupput.

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project rtbCookieServer ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/rtbCookieServer.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0/mongo -I/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/rtbCookieServer.d" -MT"src/rtbCookieServer.d" -o"src/rtbCookieServer.o" "../src/rtbCookieServer.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/rtbCookieServer.cpp

Building target: rtbCookieServer
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0 -lfcgi++  -lboost_system -lcgicc -lmongoclient -o"rtbCookieServer"  ./src/rtbCookieServer.o   
Finished building target: rtbCookieServer
```

W=hen I run the code..the is the error message I get.

```
/home/workspace/rtbCookieServer/Debug/rtbCookieServer: error while loading shared libraries: libmongoclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file is in home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0 so why cant if find it????

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Better than using LD_LIBRARY_PATH is to specify the runtime library search

```
-Wl,-rpath /home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0
```

For more information about why not using LD_LIBRARY_PATH look e.g. [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

Comment: I am using aptanta IDE.  How to I add that?  in the linker in the shared library settings?

Comment: make all 
Building target: librtbCookieServer
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0 -lfcgi++  -lboost_system -lcgicc -lmongoclient -shared -Wl,-soname=/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0 -o"librtbCookieServer"  ./src/rtbCookieServer.o   
/usr/bin/ld: ./src/rtbCookieServer.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./src/rtbCookieServer.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [librtbCookieServer] Error 1

Comment: Follow the instructions of the error message ;) `recompile with -fPIC`. It means, you've to recompile mongoDB using the `-fPIC` flag in order to allow position independant code, which is needed for shared libraries.

Comment: I tried and tried and tried to no avail.  Finally I had to place the library in /usr/lib where is worked.

Comment: But was the impact of using -fPIC when compiling mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/cpp/mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0
```

first, and try again.

The loader doesn't know the path to the library, so it has to be told where to look.

Comment: Tried to no avail.  Placed in .bashrc and in /etc/environment and reloaded source ~/.bashrc